# Is it possible to have only a single page corrupted in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, hex

In a PDF with many pages, is it possible to have only a single page be corrupted?

I've done some digging and couldn't seem to find anything so I am not even sure if this is possible, wondering if anyone has knowledge about it. And if it is possible how could I go about reproducing this? I've done some experimenting with editing hex values but it always renders the whole pdf file corrupt.

Comment: Each page in particular usually has its own content stream(s). Just corrupt such a content stream. (Strictly speaking damaging any part of a PDF results in a damaged PDF but PDF viewers might be forgiving enough to only complain on the page in question.)

Comment: This is possible, sure.... This could be e.g. a null reference in the page tree. Why do you need to reproduce this?

Comment: What kind of corruption? Unknown page description operators? Using a font that isn't defined? Using a color space that isn't there? A color space with an incorrect number of data in it? With the wrong data in it? All of those are actually quite easy to recreate with the proper tools but without knowing what you are after exactly answering is a bit of a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

A PDF is a complex object graph. A bit simplified you have

```
document
|
+ lots of objects with different purposes
+ page tree 
  |
  + .. some page
       |
       + content stream ("page description language")
       + resources
```

Now, as @mkl and @Setasign mention there's a lot you can malform in the serialization format of this network.

In your concrete document the page reference, the content stream reference, the content stream content, a resource reference in the content, a resource content,... could be the reason for failure. To debug, you will need a copy of the PDF references, the invalid file and a good PDF parser / browser tool.

*Recreating* a failure by blindly hacking hex in the document will most probably fail because of:

- the serialization format of the objects is indexed so adding/removing bytes in the middle of a page will not damage only the page, but the document.
- blindly changing some value can do damage any (structural) content, not only page content. you must restrict to changing content of items that are bound to /Contents entries only. This is where again intimate knowledge of PDF is required.

In short: it's very unlikely that you can reproduce a page rendering error by hazardly changing/adding/removing hex in a PDF.

Its like you have had a runtime error in a program and now want to recreate the error in another program by adding / removing chars...